# Does the Android web browser support x509 certificate user authentication?

Tags: browser

I'm attempting to determine if the built-in Android web browser supports user authentication using x509 certificates. Assuming I have my web server configured correctly, and I have added the user certificate to Android, will the browser support this kind of authentication?

I haven't tested this yet but I'm attempting to create a zero login mobile application for work.

Your help and feedback is greatly appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you for sure, but the Android OS supports x509 so I would assume the browser does as well.